# Evaluating the product $\prod_{p}\, \left(1- \dfrac{2}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\,\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right)^2\,$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration

I need to evaluate $$ f(s) = \prod_{p}\, \left(1- \dfrac{2}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\,\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right)^2\,.$$ This arises from $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{\Omega(n)}}{n^s} = \zeta^2 (s) \, \prod_p\, \left(1- \dfrac{2}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\,\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s} \right)^2, \, \, \, \mathscr{R}(s)>1$$

What I know is that this has a pole of order 3 at $s=1$. Then, the idea is to find the Laurent expansion of $f(s)$ and some sort of an integral formula (Perron's formula?) to find $f(s)$? Any help on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "evaluate" ? $$\log f(s) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{2^k - 2 }k p^{-sk}$$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1/2$.

$f(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1/2$.

Comment: I meant a "closed form" of $f(s)$. May be I should've added more there. The goal is to prove $\sum_{n\leq x} 2^{\Omega(n)} = c\,x (\log \, x)^2 + O(x \log{x})$. So, the Perron's formula would help but I want to find $f(s)$ (its Laurent series) in order to use the formula.

Comment: That $f(s)$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s)>3/4$ and $f(1)=c\ne 0$ and $\sum_{n\le x}\tau(n)\sim  x\log x$ is enough. There is no "closed-form" for $\prod_p (1-2 p^{-s})$

Comment: How should I start writing the equation for $\sum_{n\leq x} 2^{\Omega(n)}$?. I can do it for $\sum 2^ {\omega(n)}$ (using Mobius function) but can't figure out this one.